# android - upload a project in jcenter

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I want to upload one project in jcenter and use it with gradle . I did every step as well as told in [tutorial](http://crushingcode.co/publish-your-android-library-via-jcenter/) but I get this error :

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':upgradedmadatepicker'.
>    Could not read script 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attwellBrian/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'.
>   Network is unreachable: connect

while it is work in chrome. where is my mistake? what do I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to ask JFrog support team (JFrog is the company behind Bintray). They can probably provide you details can help you with your problem. https://www.jfrog.com/support-service/ .  I am with JFrog.